# Why select IN doesnt work properly when there are nulls

Tags: sql, database, select, in-clause, exasol

Why this is returning a record in EXASOL DBMS

```
SELECT a, b FROM (SELECT NULL AS a, 'b' AS b) t
WHERE (a, b) NOT IN (SELECT NULL, 'b')
```

?

Thanks, Rafael.

Comment: What is your exact SQL database, and also what is the outcome of the query you posted above?

Comment: Because `(NULL = NULL) <> True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `(NULL = NULL) <> True`

---

```
create table three(
        one integer
        );

INSERT INTO three(one) VALUES(1),(2),(NULL);

SELECT one.one AS one
        , two.one AS two
        , one.one = two.one AS diff
FROM three one
CROSS JOIN three two
        ;
```

---

### Result:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 3
 one | two | diff 
-----+-----+------
   1 |   1 | t
   1 |   2 | f
   1 |     | 
   2 |   1 | f
   2 |   2 | t
   2 |     | 
     |   1 | 
     |   2 | 
     |     | 
(9 rows)
```

---

So, comparing anything to NULL results in NULL, **not** True or False.

In your case, you are comparing tuples, not scalars. For tuples it is even worse: if any element of one of the tuples is NULL, the comparison result is neither True nor False.

Comment: According to SQL comparing null to null evaluates to `UNKNOWN`. A `WHERE` clause requires the predicate to evaluate to `TRUE` for the row to be included, not `FALSE`, not `UNKNOWN`.